# android SDK drawing on a picture and then saving the file as a image

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to implement code in my android app that gets a `2D` drawing from a user and then saves it as a image file. there will be a background in this. I also want it to work aside other things in my code(e.g. number picker). most examples I have seen have the entire screen dedicated to it I just want a portion of it though. However I do not know where to start. Sorry if a question like this has already been asked I have not been able to find it. I am a beginner.
[here is a screenshot of the app, I want it under the toggle buttons](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4WktV7Sh1-bWllQY0xSQ0xTT0U/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4WktV7Sh1-bWllQY0xSQ0xTT0U/view?usp=sharing